# How does the cyclisation of the 3,6-dimethylocta-2,6-dien-4-yne occur?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> [image: 3,6-dimethylocta-2,6-dien-4-yne]

The given molecule is treated with $\ce{H+}$ and an acid, that is all. I know that the alkene part reacts with the $\ce{H+}$ first, but have no idea on how to proceed further. I don't see how a cyclisation takes place as the final answer given is 3,4,5,6-tetramethyl-3-cyclohexen-1-one. Any help on how this happens?

Comment: I know you didn't draw this, but please don't draw your molecules like that, ever... the bond angles are all wrong!

Comment: Bent triple bond and inconsistent angles make me think you might want to find a better textbook. Also, please don't approve [edits that make the quality of your question worse](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/131842/2).

Comment: Also name of the final product should be 3,4,5,6-tetramethyl-2-cyclohexen-1-one (if that is the preferred one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add water to the triple bond a ketone would be formed as the molecule is symmetrical hydroxy group can be attached yo any of the two carbons after that it would undergo tautomerism to form a ketone. Now the second step cyclisation occurs as follows:

[image: The cyclization mechanism]

Comment: It seems that you just proposed a pathway to get to the answer provided in the question. I can see what you did with the aqueous acid and the tautomerism, but what about the reagents in the 2nd step? Why would they cause this cyclization, how do they operate here? I guess you should elaborate on that

Comment: The double bond is an internal neucleophile to attack at the  electrophilic site of the carbonyl compund  this triggers cyclisation then in the second step the addition of weak acids is to ensure that there would be no substitution in the compound (concentration of hydroxide in the water would be decreased)

Comment: That's not quite the reason, the acid catalyst is meant to activate the ketone for an intramolecular electrocyclization called the Nazarov cyclization reaction. You can check the mechanism [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazarov_cyclization_reaction) Double bonds are nucleophilic, but they don't just start attacking carbonyls in an alpha beta unsaturatec situation.. This is more due to the thermally allowed rotations